# State not updating in redux - React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, redux

I am fetching the data using axios in redux from which I am updating the state, but, It shows empty array in my movies component when I console log, but, when I console.log in the redux where I am fetching the data i.e getMovies() function. It displays all the data in the console. In short, the data is not being assigned to the movies variable. Take a look to the code:

in Actions.js

```
import { GET_MOVIES } from "./actionsType";
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://reactnative.dev/movies.json";

export const getMovies = () => {
  try {
    return async (dispatch) => {
      const res = await axios.get(BASE_URL);
      console.log(res.data.movies);
      const MoviesList = res.data.movies;
      console.log(MoviesList);
      if (MoviesList) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_MOVIES,
          payload: MoviesList,
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Unable to fetch");
      }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

in Reducer.js

```
import { GET_MOVIES } from "./actions";

const initialState = {
  movies: [],
};

function moviesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MOVIES:
      return { ...state, movies: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default moviesReducer;
```

in store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import moviesReducer from "./MoviesReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  moviesReducer,
});
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

in Movies.js    - this is where I want to display the data in flatlist

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { getMovies } from "../redux/actions";

const Movies = () => {
  const { movies } = useSelector((state) => state.moviesReducer);
    console.log(movies);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fetchMovies = () => dispatch(getMovies());

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 44, paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>Popular Movies</Text>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={movies}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View>
                <Text>
                  {item.title} {item.releaseYear}
                </Text>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
export default Movies;
```

you can check here when I console the (movies) it shows empty array in console but in actions where I am fetching. The data is received successfully.
Please can someone help me with this !

I tried to do change things here and there but nothing is happening. Please look at the code and provide a solution If you can

Comment: Is your selector correct? I think you want to `const movies = useSelector((state) => state.movies)` instead.

Comment: he is already using `const { movies } =` so I think on that part it is fine.

Comment: I tried this also but it shows error.

Comment: but maybe nbokmans is onto something by using `const { movies } = useSelector(( state => state);` I think a good step do debug this is in the `Reducer` adding a `console.log` and see if the reducer is actually being called with the `movies`

Comment: when I console log It shows movies as empty array

Comment: is it setting the `MoviesList` in the correct way? I think it is setting it to an empty array and an empty array resolves to `true` if you check for it with `if([]) {`

Comment: yes , because MoviesList shows the data when console logged. And I added the variable on purpose to see  whether something is not wrong with the response i am receiving. But, hopefully It works fine. Something is wrong in moviesReducer I guess

Comment: Are you sure you got data in reduces?. check one thing add one more useEffect and pass dependency what you want get when update

Comment: In the `getMovies()` Function in actions I got the data, you can see I have console logged there `MovieLists`

Comment: Can you show me how to do that